# Picard's theorem applied to $f^n + g^n =1$

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-numbers

So I have the following problem. Part 1 is just to state Picard's theorem, so for that we have that any entire holomorphic function takes on every value with possibly one exception.

Part 2 is to show that for $n\geq 2$ there are no nowhere vanishing and nonconstant entire functions $f, g$ such that $f^n+g^n=1$ The proof of that goes as follows. $f^n$ is entire, and $f^n=1-g^n$. Since $g\neq 0$, $g^n\neq 0$ hence $f^n \neq 1$ hence $f^n$ is an entire function omitting both $0$ and $1$, contradiction.

The final part is assume that $n>2$. Find all the solutions $f$ and $g$ to $f^n+g^n=1$ in the ring of entire functions. The hint is to transform the problem to the setting of meromorophic functions  on the complex line, but I don't know how to proceed.

Thanks for any help!

Comment: I didn't get part $2$. Seems like $\not\equiv$ and $\neq$ are different things. More precise: why $g\neq 0$?

Comment: Well, since $f$ is non-vanishing then neither is $f^n$. Then since $g^n$ is non-vanishing, writing $f^n=1-g^n$ shows that $f^n$ never equals 1. So then $f^n$ is entire but omits two values, contradicting Picard's theorem.

Comment: @Jihad it's part of the asumption for part 2. For part 3, you relax the assumptions of non-vanishing :P

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Assume $n \ge 3$ and $f^n+g^n=1$ for two entire functions $f, g$. Then
$$
  \bigl(\frac fg \bigr)^n + 1 = \frac 1 {g^n} \quad .
$$
The right-hand side is never zero,
which means that the meromorphic function  $h = f/g$ does not take any
of the values $w_1, \ldots, w_n$ which are defined as the solutions of $w^n = -1$.

So $h$ is meromorphic in $\mathbb C$ and omits $n \ge 3$ values and therefore must
be constant.

Or, if you prefer, $1/(h-w_1)$ is an *entire* function and omits the $ n - 1 \ge 2$ values
$1/(w_k - w_1)$, $k = 2, \ldots, n$.

Comment: So this is something I should obviously know, but don't, how many values can a meromorphic function omit, 2? Is there a name for this theorem? And thanks :)

Comment: @TheManWhoNeverSleeps: Yes, a meromorphic function in C can omit at most 2 values and that is also called Picard's theorem. It can easily be reduced to the case of entire functions. I have added that to the answer.

Comment: I think that clears it up. Thanks!